# Having the derivative be an operator

Tags: custom-notation, operators

How do I create an operator which acts like a derivative to everything to the right of it:

for example:

$ \left( \partial_x + \partial_y + z \right ) x \psi $

How do I make that evaluate to:

$x \partial_x \psi + \psi + x \partial_y \psi + z x \psi $

(I want the derivatives to distribute...)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A general idea as to how this can be done in a consistent way is explained in the help documents under [NonCommutativeMultiply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html). The thing is that you want to use your operators in an algebraic notation, and that's what that page discusses.

If, on the other hand, you're happy with a more formal Mathematica notation, then you would have the easier task of defining operators simply as

```
dx := D[#, x] &
dy := D[#, y] &
```

and using them as follows:

```
dx@f[x, y, z]
```

> $f^{(1,0,0)}(x,y,z)$

Combining operators would then be done using `Composition`:

```
dxy = Composition[dx, dy];
dxy[f[x, y, z]]
```

> $f^{(1,1,0)}(x,y,z)$

**Edit**

Here is another approach that's sort of intermediate between the very simple `D[#,x]&` scheme and the more complicated realization of an operator algebra in the linked reference from the documentation.

To make the operators satisfy the axioms of a *vector space*, we'd have to define their addition among each other and the multiplication with scalars. This can be done most conveniently if we don't use patterns to represent the operators, but `Function`s. So here I repeat the operator definitions - they act the same way as the `dx`, `dy` defined above, but their definition is stored differently:

```
dx = Function[{f}, D[f, x]];
dy = Function[{f}, D[f, y]];
```

Now I define the multiplication of an operator with a scalar:

```
multiplyOp[scalar_, op_] := Function[{f1}, scalar op[f1]];
```

For simplicity, I always assume that the scalar is given as the first argument, and the second argument is an operator, e.g., `dx` etc. Note that the arguments here are not `x` or `y` (the assumed independent variables on which functions depend), because `multiplyOp` maps operators onto operators.

Finally, we need the addition of two (or more) operators, which is again a mapping from operators (a sequence of them) onto operators:

```
addOps[ops__] := Function[{f1}, Total@Map[#[f1] &, {ops}]];
```

Both addition and multiplication are mapped back to their usual meaning in these functions, by defining how the combined new operators act on a test function `f1` (which is in turn a function of `x`, `y`, and `z` - depending on the dimension).

To illustrate the way these operations are used, take the example in the question,

$\left(\partial_x+\partial_y+z\right)x\psi$

and write it with our syntax:

```
addOps[dx, dy, multiplyOp[z, Identity]]@(x ψ[x, y])
```

> $x \psi ^{(0,1)}(x,y)+x \psi ^{(1,0)}(x,y)+\psi (x,y)+x z \psi (x,y)$

This is the correct result (the result quoted originally in the post was actually missing an `x`).

Note how I added the scalar `z` above: in this syntax, it first has to be made into an operator using `multiplyOp[z, Identity]`. The `Identity` operator is very useful for this.

Of course these expressions with `addOps` and `multiplyOp` aren't as easy to read as the ones with simple `+` signs, but on the bright side it can also be beneficial pedagogically to separate the "operator operations" clearly from the operations between the functions they *act on*.

**Edit 2**

In response to the comment, I'll add a nicer notation, but without modifying the last approach. So I'll simply introduce new symbols for the operations defined above, using some of the operator symbols that Mathematica *knows* in terms of their operator precedence, but has no pre-defined meanings for:

- `CirclePlus` ⊕ typed as <kbd>esc</kbd>c+<kbd>esc</kbd>
- `CircleDot` ⊙ typed as <kbd>esc</kbd>c.<kbd>esc</kbd>
- `CircleTimes` ⊗ typed as <kbd>esc</kbd>c*<kbd>esc</kbd>

I'll use them as follows:

```
CirclePlus[ops__] := addOps[ops];
CircleDot[scalar_, op_] := multiplyOp[scalar, op];
CircleTimes[ops__] := Composition[ops];
```

With this, we can now use `Infix` notation to write in a more "natural" fashion:

```
(dx ⊕ dy ⊕ z⊙Identity)@(x ψ[x,y])
```

> $x \psi ^{(0,1)}(x,y)+x \psi ^{(1,0)}(x,y)+\psi (x,y)+x z \psi (x,y)$

As the third operator, `CircleTimes` ⊗, I've also defined the composition of operators. That allows us to do things like commutators:

```
commutator = dx ⊗ x⊙Identity ⊕ (-x)⊙Identity ⊗ dx;
```

I'm relying on the fact that ⊙ has higher precedence than ⊗ which in turn has higher precedence than ⊕ (according to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html)).

As expected, the commutator is unity, as we can check by applying to a test function:

```
commutator@f[x]
```

> `f[x]`

Comment: very nicely done.  I imagine it would be possible to unprotect and modify the addition and multiplication signs to make this simpler to read?

Comment: @AndrewSpott I've added a more readable notation in a way that doesn't require unprotecting `Times` and `Plus`, so the symbols used for operators are still distinct from the usual ones, but more intuitive (I hope) than before.

Comment: thanks!  that is really slick.  The commutator is actually what I'm interested in, thanks.

Answer (score 21):

**Update**

I've created a paclet. Install with:

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/carlwoll/DifferentialOperator/releases/download/0.1/DifferentialOperator-0.0.1.paclet"]
```

and load with:

```
<<DifferentialOperator`
```

**Original post**

Here's an approach I've been playing with that attempts to mimic traditional notation for these kinds of operators. The exposition is a little long, but the payoff is a very natural approach to handling operators.

**DifferentialOperator**

The first step is to create an operator form for derivatives that can be entered easily using the keyboard, and formats as expected.  I call the operator form `DifferentialOperator`, and it has the following [`SubValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubValues)/[`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues):

```
DifferentialOperator[z__:x][f_] := D[f, z]

DifferentialOperator /: DifferentialOperator[z__:x]^n_Integer?Positive := Apply[
    DifferentialOperator,
    Flatten @ ConstantArray[{z}, n]
]
```

Here is an example:

```
L = DifferentialOperator[x, y]
L @ Exp[x y]
```

> DifferentialOperator[x, y]
>
> E^(x y) + E^(x y) x y

The above definition is a nice operator form, but the formatting is rather long, so I give `DifferentialOperator` a nice format below:

```
DifferentialOperator /: MakeBoxes[DifferentialOperator[], form_] := InterpretationBox[
    "\[PartialD]", DifferentialOperator[]
]

DifferentialOperator /: MakeBoxes[DifferentialOperator[x__], form_] := With[
    {sub = RowBox @ BoxForm`MakeInfixForm[{x},",", form]},

    InterpretationBox[
        SubscriptBox["\[PartialD]",sub],
        DifferentialOperator[x]
    ]
]
```

Now, the operator `L` looks much more like the usual derivative operator:

```
L //TeXForm
```

> $\partial _{x,y}$

Finally, typing `DifferentialOperator` is rather tedious and ugly, so I use [`InputAutoReplacements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAutoReplacements) to streamline the input:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAutoReplacements] = {
    "pd" -> TemplateBox[
        {"\"\[PartialD]\""},
        "Partial",
        DisplayFunction -> (StyleBox[#, ShowStringCharacters->False]&),
        InterpretationFunction -> (
            RowBox[{"operator", "[", RowBox[{"DifferentialOperator","[","]"}],"]"}]&
        ),
        Editable->False,
        Selectable->False
    ],
    ParentList
};
```

A few comments here:

a. I use a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) so that editing of the `\[PartialD` string is prevented.

b. I use `"\"\[PartialD]\""` instead of just `"\[PartialD]"` so that input parsing works as expected.

c. I use [`ShowStringCharacters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowStringCharacters)->[`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False) so that one doesn't see the quotes I added above.

d. The [`InterpretationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpretationFunction) includes an `operator` wrapper that will be discussed later.

Here is a short animation showing me enter the OP operator into an input cell:

[image]

**Composition**

Differential operators don't commute with expressions, e.g., $\partial ⋅ x \neq x ⋅ \partial$, so I will use [`CenterDot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CenterDot)  for composition of operators.

I can't just use [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition) because scalar operators have an implied [`Identity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Identity), but I can give [`CenterDot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CenterDot) special rules to accommodate this. Here are the arithmetical rules:

```
(* arithmetic *)
CenterDot[___, 0, ___] = 0;

CenterDot[a_, c__] + CenterDot[b_, c__] ^:= CenterDot[a+b,c]
a_?scalarQ CenterDot[b_, c___] ^:= CenterDot[a b, c]
```

and the operator rules ([`SubValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubValues)):

```
SetAttributes[CenterDot,{Flat,OneIdentity}]

(* nested function application *)
CenterDot[a__, b_][x_] := CenterDot[a][CenterDot[b][x]]

(* function application *)
CenterDot[a_Plus][x_] := CenterDot[#][x]&/@a
CenterDot[a_?scalarQ][x_] := a x
CenterDot[a_?scalarQ b_?differentialQ][x_] := a CenterDot[b][x]
CenterDot[d_DifferentialOperator][x_] := d[x]
```

**The `operator` wrapper**

You may have noticed the `operator` wrapper in the above [`InterpretationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpretationFunction). Suppose one were to use $L = \partial + x$. Without the `operator` wrapper, the head would just be [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus), and applying `L` to a function `L[f]` would evaluate to `Plus[DifferentialOperator[], x][f]`, and in order to have this evaluate further one would need to modify the `` System` `` symbol `Plus` (not a good idea). The `operator` wrapper automatically absorbs typical arithmetic operations so that arithmetic with an `operator` object will produce an `operator` object. This means that `L[f]` evaluates to an `operator` object, and we can give rules for `operator` in order to get the operator to act on a function. Here are the definitions for `operator`:

```
SetAttributes[operator, {Flat, OneIdentity}]

(* addition *)
operator[a_]+c_ ^:= operator[a+c]

(* scalar multiplication *)
c_?scalarQ operator[a_] ^:= operator[c a]

(* composition *)
operator[a_,b__] := operator[CenterDot[a,b]]

operator[a_]\[CenterDot]c_ ^:= operator[CenterDot[a,c]]
c_\[CenterDot]operator[a_] ^:= operator[CenterDot[c,a]]

(* power *)
operator /: operator[a_]^n_Integer := operator[CenterDot@@ConstantArray[a,n]]

(* subscripted nabla *)
Subscript[operator[DifferentialOperator[]], x__] ^:= operator[DifferentialOperator[x]]

(* utilities*)
scalarQ = FreeQ[DifferentialOperator];
differentialQ = Not @* scalarQ;
```

Some examples:

[image]

Notice how the head of every expression is `operator`. Now, we can give a definition for `operator`:

```
(* function application *)
operator[a_][x_] := CenterDot[a][x]
```

Finally, we need a format for operator, as we don't want to see it in the input or output:

```
operator/:MakeBoxes[operator[a__], form_]:=If[Length@Hold[a]>1,
    StyleBox[MakeBoxes[CenterDot[a], form], Bold],
    StyleBox[MakeBoxes[a, form], Bold]
]
```

I use [`Bold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Bold) to indicate that the object is an operator:

```
L = Subscript[operator[DifferentialOperator[]], t,t] - 3 Subscript[operator[DifferentialOperator[]], t] + 2;
L //TeXForm
```

> $\bf{\partial _{t,t}-3 \partial _t+2}$

**Examples**

That's it for the framework. Now, for the example in this question, we have:

[image]

*Some other examples.*

A commutator:

[image]

Operator arithmetic:

[image]

Question [(15605)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15605/45431):

[image]

Question [(43775)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43775/45431):

[image]

Question [(20519)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20519/45431):

[image]

I haven't included it here, but the next step is to perform simplifications of the `CenterDot` objects, in particular so that commutators can be defined.

Comment: Good work. I added some rules for the composition of differential operators in tensor form.

Answer (score 15):

Something like this

```
f = D[#, x] + D[#, y] + z # &
```

seems to work.  Use as follows:

```
f[x ψ[x, y, z]]
```

to give

> $x \psi ^{(0,1,0)}(x,y,z)+x \psi ^{(1,0,0)}(x,y,z)+x z \psi (x,y,z)+\psi (x,y,z)$

Answer (score 10):

Since no one mentioned it yet, `Through` can do something similar:

```
(Derivative[1, 0] + Derivative[0, 1])[f] // Through
```

will evaluate to

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

This simple solution will work only on conmutative operators:

```
applyOp[anything_] := 
     Expand[anything] //. Times[d : Except[_Function] .., a__Function] 
                          :> (Composition[a][Times[d]])
```

And defining operators like Jens:

```
dx := D[#, x] &
dy := D[#, y] &
```

But no need to define `z` as operator. You can do:

```
applyOp[(dx + dy + z) (x psi[x, y, z])]
(* --->
psi[x,y,z]+x z psi[x,y,z]+x (psi^(0,1,0))[x,y,z]+x (psi^(1,0,0))[x,y,z]
*)
```

**EDITED**: Composition of operators is only on conmutative operators, derivatives are not.

Comment: Your last example uses non-commuting operators (`dx` and `x` don't commute, nor do `dy` and `y`) and therefore violates the restriction you identified yourself (try `da := D[#,a]&; applyOp[da a]` to see a result which you surely didn't expect). However your suggestion has a more important flaw: You do not distinguish between the operator and the function it is applied to. Most importantly, the operator $\partial_x f(\hat x)$ is *not* the same as the operator $f'(\hat x)$, but equals the operator $(f'(\hat x) + f(\hat x)\partial_x)$.

Comment: @celtschk you are totally right. I should not answer at nights... I will change it to a non-conmutative way.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want. Anyway:

```
d[psi_[a_, b_, c_]] := D[psi, a] + D[psi, b] + c psi

p[x_, y_, z_] := x + y;

d[p[x, y, z]]
(*
-> 2 + (x + y) z
*)
```