# How to define a non-standard algebra in Mathematica?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, operators

I want to define an algebra, where there are three elements: 0, 1 and $\infty$ and two operations, addition and multiplication defined, both commutative:

$$\begin{align*}
0+0&=0\\
0+1&=1\\
0+\infty&=\infty\\
1+1&=1\\
1+\infty&=\infty\\
\infty+\infty&=\infty\\
0\times0&=0\\
1\times0&=0\\
1\times1&=1\\
0\times\infty&=1\\
1\times\infty&=\infty\\
\infty\times\infty&=\infty
\end{align*}$$

I want Mathematica to simplify expressions in this system.

Comment: You might want to look into using `CirclePlus[]` and `CircleTimes[]` for defining your special operations, as it's usually not a good idea to modify `Plus[]` and `Times[]` willy-nilly.

Comment: A related discussion of custom notation for an operator algebra: [Having the derivative be an operator](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5032/245)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
Begin["NonStandardAlgebra`"];
ClearAll /@ {plus, times};
SetAttributes[#, Orderless] & /@ {plus, times};
plus[x : 0 | 1, y : 0 | 1] := Unitize[x + y]
plus[Infinity, x : 0 | 1 | Infinity] := Infinity
times[0, Infinity] := 1
times[x_, y_] := System`Times[x, y]
End[];
```

A couple of examples:

```
NonStandardAlgebra`times[Infinity, 0]
(* 1 *)

NonStandardAlgebra`plus[1, 1]
(* 1 *)
```

To make the usage convenient, you can utilize an unused symbol. Here, I map these to `CirclePlus` and `CircleTimes` respectively as:

```
CirclePlus[x_, y_] := NonStandardAlgebra`plus[x, y]
CircleTimes[x_, y_] := NonStandardAlgebra`times[x, y]
```

Here's your entire algebra (the bottom line is the output):

[image]

Comment: Will it simplify complex expressions?

Comment: what sort of expressions do you have in mind? Have you tried it with your expressions? You should add such info to the question before posting.

Comment: @Anixx: why not try it out yourself? BTW: you didn't mention if associativity is a property of your algebra...

Comment: I wonder whether it will derive associativity ans distributivity laws itself.

Comment: the tables I provided are enough for such derivation.

Comment: I want it do derive all the properties of the new algebra for itself, just taking the tables of addition and multiplication as the input.

Comment: @Anixx: okay then... `Function[{a, b, c}, a\[CirclePlus](b\[CirclePlus]c) == (a\[CirclePlus]b)\[CirclePlus]c] @@@ Apply[Join, Permutations /@ Tuples[{0, 1, Infinity}, 3]]`

Comment: Also, `Function[{a, b, c}, a\[CircleTimes](b\[CirclePlus]c) == (a\[CircleTimes]b)\[CirclePlus](a\[CircleTimes]c)] @@@ Apply[Join, Permutations /@ Tuples[{0, 1, Infinity}, 3]]`

Comment: But can it automatically simplify the expressions with unknown variables? For example, simplify $(a\otimes b)\oplus (a\otimes c)$ to $a\otimes (b\oplus c)$?

Comment: @Anixx: Commutativity should already be accounted for by the line `SetAttributes[#,Orderless]&/@{plus,times};`. To account for associativity as well, you can change `Orderless` to `{Flat,Orderless}` in that line. I don't think there's an attribute for distributivity, though.

Answer (score 11):

Since your addition and multiplication have the usual properties (associativity, commutativity, distributivity), another option is to use normal plus and times, but different symbols, e.g. `zero`, `one` and `inf` for your elements. Then you can write:

```
zero + x_ ^= x;
inf + x_ ^= inf;
one + one ^= one;
zero * zero ^= zero;
zero * inf ^= one;
one * x_ ^= x;
one * inf ^= inf;
inf * inf ^= inf;
```

Then you have

```
{zero + zero, one + zero, zero + inf, one + inf, inf + inf, zero * zero,
 one * zero, one * one, zero * inf, one * inf, inf * inf}
(*
==> {zero, one, inf, inf, inf, zero, zero, one, one, inf, inf}
*)
```

Comment: If one takes this route, symbols like `\[ScriptZero]` and `\[ScriptOne]` might be useful.

Comment: In both methods the computer does not derive distributivity and associativity itself,

Comment: @Anixx: I just tried with my method `(a+b)*one == a*one+b*one //Simplify` and got `True` as expected. And associativity should be automatic due to `Plus` and `Times` having attribute `Flat`. The same is true for commutativity and `Orderless`. Do you have a concrete example that fails?