# Noncommutative multiply- expand expression

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I began to use *Mathematica* a few days ago. My problem is: how do I expand expressions like $(a+b)\ast(a+b)$, where the multiplication is noncommutative? Can *Mathematica* do this?

Comment: Maybe `Distribute[(a + b) ** (a + b) ]` ?

Comment: Look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22824/defining-a-non-commutative-operator-algebra-in-mathematica/22832#22832) for some more thoughts about non commutative multiplication and more ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Distribute[]` is a useful thing:

```
Distribute[(a + b) ** (c + d)]
   a ** c + a ** d + b ** c + b ** d
```

Comment: Although this works on the example used by jon, it doesn't really answer the question satisfactorily (although the question was vague).   For instance, it does *not* work on `Distribute[a.(c + d)/2]`.

Comment: @Jess, yes, that case is a little problematic.OTOH, a rearrangement of that expression, along with using the second and third arguments of `Distribute[]` succeeds: `Distribute[(a/2).(c + d), Plus, Dot]`

Comment: I mean, ok, but the whole point of this is to avoid re-arranging the expressions by hand, because the cases when you really want to use this are when you have 30 terms.

Comment: It doesn't work for expression with sum. For example `Distribute[(a + b) ** (c + d) + a ** (b + d)]`

Comment: @dtn, indeed, so one has to use `/.` in such cases, e.g. `(a + b) ** (c + d) + a ** (b + d) /. 
 nc_NonCommutativeMultiply :> Distribute[nc]`.

Comment: @J.M. is it possible to do the reverse assembly operation?

Comment: @dtn, sounds like that could be a new question.

Comment: @J.M. let's try https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268454/noncommutative-multiply-expand-expression-and-then-assembly-back

Answer (score 6):

The package [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) does exactly what you want.

```
NCExpand[(a + b) ** (a + b)]
(* a ** a + a ** b + b ** a + b ** b *)
```