# How to write or extend operators like $*\!\!*$

Tags: programming, function-construction, pattern-matching, reference-request

I'm stuck on trying to define simplification rules for NonCommutativeMultiply, much like ExpandNCM found in [Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html), under Applications.

For example, I'd like `1**x = x`, `x**1 = x`, `x**(1/x) = (1/x)**x = 1`, i.e., I'd like to write rules that would mimic those of multiplication in [non-commutative unital ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29#Definition).

I'm not looking for code (although I wouldn't object if someone would provide one), but for reference where I can learn to write such things myself. My knowledge of Mathematica is basic, I know how to write simple functions, and would like to learn how to write functions using pattern matching.

More generally, I'm interested to know how one could write operation like NonCommutativeMultiply from scratch, that is how could one mimic associativity: `(x**y)**z == x**(y**z)`.

Comment: Does [this link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22824/defining-a-non-commutative-operator-algebra-in-mathematica) help?

Comment: As far as mimicking associativity, `NonCommutativeMultiply` already has the attribute `Flat`, which is (I think) *Mathematica*'s way of mimicking associativity. In the documentation for `Flat`: `f[f[a, b], f[c, f[d, e]]]` automatically becomes `f[a, b, c, d, e]` if `f` has the `Flat` `Attribute`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, thank you, I'll need some time to go through that.

Comment: @march, thank you. I already knew that `NonCommutativeMultiply` is associative, but I didn't know about `Flat` `Attribute`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to extend the definition of `NonCommutativeMultiply`?

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
x_ ** 1 := x
1 ** x_ := x
x_ ** Power[x_, -1] := 1
Power[x_, -1] ** x_ := 1
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

After evaluating the above code

```
y ** 1
```

> `y`

```
1 ** y
```

> `y`

```
y ** (1/y)
```

> `1`

```
(1/y) ** y
```

> `1`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was hoping for. I did try this, but wasn't aware of `Unprotect`.