# Custom display format for custom operator

Tags: formatting, custom-notation, display

I've tried searching here and in the WRI documentation, but I haven't found what I'm looking for in either place.

I'm defining a `dx` operator to act as a shorthand for `D[#,x]`, based on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5030/having-the-derivative-be-an-operator). 
In my case, I want *Mathematica* to produce an output form with the text `d/dx` *expression* `= [...]`, where by `[...]` I mean the actual symbolic meaning of my `dx` operator (i.e., `D[#, x]`).

I have tried this:

```
Format[dx[a_] := "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(d\), \(dx\)]\)"  a  "="  D[a, x]]
```

I've also tried

```
Format[dx[#], TraditionalForm] := 
  DisplayForm[
    RowBox[{FractionBox["\DifferentialD]", "\[DifferentialD]x"],
    #, "=", D[#, x]}]];
```

and various other similar things, none of which produce the correct expression.

I would appreciate help with getting this right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
dx /: MakeBoxes[dx[a_], fmt_] := 
  RowBox[{FractionBox["\[PartialD]", "\[PartialD]x"], 
    MakeBoxes[a, fmt], "=", MakeBoxes[#, fmt] &@D[a, x]}];

dx[Sin[x]]
```

[image]

```
dx[Sin[x]] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

I prefer `MakeBoxes` but it also can be implemented with `Format`

```
ClearAll[dx]

Format[dx[a_]] := 
  DisplayForm@RowBox[{FractionBox["\[PartialD]", "\[PartialD]x"], MakeBoxes[a], 
     "=", MakeBoxes[#] &@D[a, x]}];

dx[Sin[x]]
```

[image]

Comment: What does the MakeBoxes[#] refer to? Does it refer to the result supplied by the later @D function?

Comment: @Trevor `MakeBoxes[#]&@D[a, x]` inserts evaluated `D[a, x]` into `MakeBoxes`. `Evaluate` doesn't work here because `MakeBoxes` has `HoldAllComplete` attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will learn your answer. It has great value for me.