# Differential operator squared

Tags: functions, function-construction, operators

I defined a one-dimensional momentum operator $\hat{p}=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}$ in Mathematica

```
p = -I * h * D[#, x]&
```

and I want to get the kinetic energy operator $\hat{T}=\hat{p}^2/2m=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ from it, so

```
T = p^2/(2m)
```

but it gives the wrong result

What can I do about it? Do I have to derive the operators by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just squre an operator since no multiplication of functions (operators) are defined in Mathematica. You have to write something like

```
T = (p@p@#)/(2 m) &
```

or

```
T = p[p[#]]/(2 m) &
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a more generalized method for what you want to do:

Let's define our momentum operator as you did above:

```
P := -I * h * D[#, x]&
```

Then we can define the nth power operator in a more general way as:

```
T[n_] := Nest[P, #, n] &
```

So for example the Kinetic energy operator (which is `P^2 / (2 m)`) will be:

```
T[2] / (2 m)
```

And we can use it on some function `f` as follows

```
(1/ (2 m))T[2]@(E^(I k x))
```

Which gives:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

as expected.

Now if we want `P^3` we just use `T[3]` etc.