# SphericalHarmonicY does not seem to be an eigenfunction of the spherical harmonic equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I applied the [spherical harmonic equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalHarmonic.html) on the `SphericalHarmonicY` functions like this:

```
Simplify[(1/Sin[θ]) D[Sin[θ] D[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ], θ], θ] + 
    (1/Sin[θ]^2) D[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ], {ϕ, 2}]]
```

And it returns a sum of factors with $Y^{m}_{l}(\theta, \phi)$, $Y^{m+1}_{l}(\theta, \phi)$ and $Y^{m+2}_{l}(\theta, \phi)$

This is counterintuitive. I thought these were the eigenfunctions of the operator. I feel like I might be missing something basic here.

Comment: Even if one uses `FullSimplify[]`, the problem seems to be in the fact that *Mathematica* does not seem to recognize a particular difference equation satisfied by the associated Legendre polynomial.

Comment: Using `FunctionExpand[Exp[-I m ϕ] ... ]` and adding the assumption to `FullSimplify` that `m` is an integer also do not help.  However, plotting the result over `{θ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}` certainly yields zero for any integer `m`.

Comment: @J.M. This seems pretty silly. Apart from expansions in spherical harmonics, it seems to me that Ylm being an eigenfunction of this particular differential operator is the *defining feature* of the spherical harmonics. It strikes me as a little, I don't know, unorthodox that the *Mathematica* programmers shouldn't include this naturally behind the scenes. *Much less* for the Legendre polynomials.

Comment: Another data point: if you use `FunctionExpand[FullSimplify[(* stuff *)]]` on the [full eigenvalue PDE](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/SphericalHarmonicYGeneral/13/02/0002/), you get `True` as the result. So, it can simplify that, but it cannot do the intermediate step of simplifying your expression to a single instance of `SphericalHarmonicY[]`.

Comment: So is Mathematica doing something about it ? Is there a forum where I can post this problem ? Because I am doing something in AdS4 and simplification seems to depend on this fact.

Comment: @Jaswin, if the OP won't mind, you could edit his question with your addendum; in particular, the spherical harmonic expression that you are trying to simplify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operator in the question can be simplified by first applying it to an arbitrary function `f`:

```
Simplify[(1/Sin[θ]) D[Sin[θ] D[f[θ,ϕ],θ],θ]+(1/Sin[θ]^2) D[f[θ,ϕ],{ϕ,2}]]
```

> $$f^{(2,0)}(\theta ,\phi )+\cot (\theta ) f^{(1,0)}(\theta
>    ,\phi )+\csc ^2(\theta ) f^{(0,2)}(\theta ,\phi )$$

This can be recognized as the negative of the squared angular momentum operator, $-L^2$, see below (and see also [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45946/245)). It doesn't seem possible to do the simplification exactly as asked for in the question, but you can put together a *Mathematica* based proof of the desired eigenvalue property 
$$L^2 Y^{m}_{\ell} = \ell (\ell +1) Y^{m}_{\ell}$$
in several steps. In doing so, the advantage is that you can see more clearly how this equation is related to the properties of the angular-momentum operator (the brute-force approach in the question would be shorter, but less illuminating, even if it were possible).

The spherical harmonics are simultaneous eigenfunctions of the squared angular momentum and its z component. Here is how you can verify this by asking *Mathematica* to derive the two corresponding eigenvalues:

First I define the two operators to make the notation in the following steps clearer. Then I apply these operators in the eigenvalue equation with the spherical harmonic as the assumed solution. The proof consists in the fact that *Mathematica* does indeed find an eigenvalue that makes each relation true.

```
Clear[θ, ϕ, f, m, ℓ]
lzOp = Function[f, (-I)*D[f, {ϕ}]];
l2Op = Function[f, -D[f, {θ, 2}] - Csc[θ]^2*D[f, {ϕ, 2}] - Cot[θ]*D[f, {θ}]];

Simplify[
 lzOp[SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ, m, θ, ϕ]]]
```

> `m SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ, m, θ, ϕ]`

```
Simplify[
 l2Op[SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ, ℓ, θ, ϕ]]]
```

> `ℓ (1 + ℓ) SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ, ℓ, θ, ϕ]`

So both `lzOp` (the z-angular momentum) and `l2Op` (the squared angular momentum) reproduce the spherical harmonic with a prefactor that corresponds to the correct eigenvalue.

*However*, the last eigenvalue equation with `l2Op` (which is what the question focuses on) only works for `m = ℓ`. For the remaining values of `m`, I would proceed by using the ladder operators which turn $Y^m_{\ell}$ into $Y^{m\pm 1}_{\ell}$ and also commute with `l2Op`. These operations will then necessarily leave the eigenvalue `ℓ (1 + ℓ)` unchanged for `l2Op`.

To execute this idea, I have to define the **lowering operator**, `lMinus`:

```
lMinus = Function[f, Exp[-I ϕ] (Cot[θ] D[f, ϕ] + I D[f, θ])];
```

First I now show that `lMinus` indeed has the effect of lowering the z eigenvalue of any spherical harmonic:

```
Simplify[
 First[Solve[
   lzOp[lMinus@SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ, m, θ, ϕ]] ==
     eigenvalue lMinus@SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ, m, θ, ϕ], 
   eigenvalue]
 ]]
```

> `{eigenvalue -> -1 + m}`

Here I had to use `Solve` to extract the eigenvalue property by defining the unknown `eigenvalue` as a prefactor in front of the expected functional form `lMinus@SphericalHarmonicY`. Without this trick, the functions are too complicated, and `FullSimplify` can't bring them into the same form on both sides. Note that I have only cheated a *little* here, because I didn't tell *Mathematica* what the new eigenvalue is expected to be. It found that out by itself.

The last eigenvalue equation means that if the original spherical harmonic had index `m`, then the result of `lMinus` has index `m -1`. We could now apply this operator to the "maximal state" $Y^{\ell}_{\ell}$ for which I had already shown that the eigenvalue equation $L^2 Y^{\ell}_{\ell} = \ell (\ell +1) Y^{\ell}_{\ell}$ is satisfied. Then it remains to be shown that the same eigenvalue of $L^2$ is obtained with the function created by repeated application of `lMinus` (one writes it $L_{-}$). The crucial fact that is needed for that proof is this commutation relation:

$$L^2 L_{-} = L_{-} L^2$$

which I show here by applying both orders to an arbitrary test function $f(\theta, \phi)$:

```
Simplify[
 l2Op[lMinus[f[θ, ϕ]]] == lMinus[l2Op[f[θ, ϕ]]]]
```

> `True`

With this, I have all the building blocks to deduce that

$$L^2 Y^{m}_{\ell} = \ell (\ell +1) Y^{m}_{\ell}$$

holds. You start by setting $m=\ell$, for which the above is known to be true from earlier. Then apply `lMinus` on both sides to get the same equation for $m=\ell -1$, and repeat another $2\ell$ times to span the entire angular-momentum ladder of allowed `m` for the given `ℓ`.

Comment: This is a very indirect way of dealing, what if I am using these functions and want simplifications of eigenvalue equations ?

Comment: @Jaswin The same difficulties arise with other eigenvalue equations that involve different special functions, e.g., the Coulomb problem or the harmonic oscillator. The trick of using `Solve` to derive the eigenvalue works in all these cases. I need that here to show the properties of `lMinus`, but it's actually not needed for the other eigenvalue properties (see the edit to my answer). But this is pretty much the simplest form of a proof for the general eigenvalue property that I could come up with.

Comment: @Jaswin, that's why I was prompting you in the comments to include examples in the post.

Comment: @J.M : Actually I was a bit busy, so couldn't update, and the days for giving away bounty points was yesterday, so closed the answer. Will put the updated question soon.

Answer (score 0):

In this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) you will find the relationship between the spherical harmonics and the associated Legendre Polynomials. The second of the recurrence formula from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials) gives you a relationship for same l different m's. That is the origin of [this formula](http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/SphericalHarmonicY/17/01/01/0003/) to simplify MMA's answer.