Modern way to do quantum optics calculations in 2024?
Quantum Optics can often require messy algebraic simplifications of noncommuting operators (usually ladder operators and commutators). I've asked here about how to do it before.
What are some modern techniques for doing quantum optics calculations in Mathematica?
I know of this old quantum mechanics package. I've tried to use it many times and haven't really managed to get something that feels actually useful as compared to working it out by hand.
Another suggestion at the time was to use the NCAlgebra package.
Any other ideas?

May be you can, as a preamble, write a community post about representative calculations in your field of expertise and how Mathematica and other relevant packages have helped you so far.

@Syed, ok I added some more context to the type of questions that are typically solved.

@henrikshumacher thanks I fixed it

Explicit examples with input and desired output would be helpful. Absent such, this really does not seem like a complete question for MSE purposes.

@DanielLichtblau quantum optics is an entire field of physics and I am curious if any common Mathematica practices or packages have become standard in the last 10 years. For example, does anyone actually use this quantum package from 15 years ago? Or do people use the NCAlgebra? or nothing at all?

It seems like it might be better suited for Wolfram Community. MSE is intended for more specific types of questions (or at least that’s my understanding).

Similar questions have been asked and are well recieved, see: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164790/is-there-a-way-to-do-quantum-computing-in-mathematica-notebook?rq=1

I think your question is too general. What's wrong with old solutions? What exactly functionality are you missing? What problem you are currently trying to solve?
