# Is it possible to perform the following computation in mathematica?

Tags: physics

Consider the following defined commutation relations:

$$[\hat a,\hat a^{\dagger}]=1$$

$$[\hat b,\hat b^{\dagger}]=1$$

$$[\hat a,\hat b]=0$$

(where the usual algebra of commutators holds)

Let us now consider the operator:

$$\hat H=\hat a^{\dagger}\hat a+\hat b^{\dagger}\hat b+\hat a^{\dagger}\hat a(b^{\dagger}+b)+(a^{\dagger}+a)(b^{\dagger}+b)$$

I now want to evaluate the following using Mathematica:
$$e^{\hat A}\hat He^{−\hat A}=[\hat A,\hat H]+[\hat A,[\hat A,\hat H]]+[\hat A,[\hat A,[\hat A,\hat H]]].....$$

where,
$\hat A=(\hat a^{\dagger}-\hat a+\hat b^{\dagger}-\hat b)$

As can be seen, this is a really difficult task to perform by hand and I want to use Mathematica to do it. Since I am new at Mathematica, I don't even know how to begin.

Maybe I would have to somehow define the above relations as rules but I don't then know how to make Mathematica follow the commutator algebra rules.

I am not looking for a complete solution (though it's okay if it comes as an answer since I can always use it to match with my code:), just a guide on how to start this problem in Mathematica.

**EDIT:**
From the link in the comment by evanb I realized that it's rather hard to do this in Mathematica. Has anybody used the SNEG package who can guide me on how to install or use it in Mathematica?

I am hoping that that should make my work easier. Since explicitly writing the code might take a very long time. I even have to change $\hat A$ in the above expression and try for many such $\hat A$'s.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95616/7936

Comment: Also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63811/7936

Comment: The expression you're looking for is $e^\hat{A} \hat{H} e^{-\hat{A}}$ by the Baker-Hausdorff lemma.  I assume that you already knew this, but if other non-physicists try to answer the question it might allow them to do an end run around calculating the entire series.  (In particular, if you had a finite-dimensional representation of the operators, you could use `MatrixExponential`;  but I suspect from the context that no such representation exists.)

Comment: @Michael Seifert Yes. I have directly written the expansion of the above. I will edit and add the expression above.  Also, I think the name of the above expansion is Hadamard Lemma.  Baker-Hausdorff lemma is for the expansion of $e^{\hat A}e^{\hat B}$ I think.

Comment: It's called the "Baker-Hausdorff lemma" in Sakurai's *Modern Quantum Mechanics* (not to be confused with the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula), which gives us an expansion for $e^\hat{A} e^\hat{B}$.)  But it's entirely possible that there are other names for it.