# Computing with matrix differential operators

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, operators

I am looking the achieve a working set of Mathematica functions that would allow me to take products, commutators, etc. of (2x2) matrix differential operators and apply them to vector-valued functions of the form {f[x], g[x]}.

Here is what I have now and the problem I am encountering. The function

```
CircleTimes[a_,b_]:=Inner[Composition[#1,#2]&,a,b]
```

does the right job of computing the matrix operator resulting from the product of two matrix differential operators a and b. With the function

```
CenterDot[a_,v_]:=Inner[Through[#1[#2]&, Plus],a, v]
```

one can compute the action of the matrix differential operator a on the vector-valued function v, and it seems to be working fine.

Problems arise when I want to compute the products of more than 2 operators or their commutator on vector-valued functions.

For example, if one defines

```
d=CircleTimes[a,CircleTimes[b,c]]
```

which is the matrix operator corresponding to a x b x c, then

```
v=CenterDot[d,{f[x],g[x]}]
```

does not produce anything useful. The same happens if we define for example the anticommutator

```
e=Plus[CircleTimes[a,b], CircleTimes[b,a]]
```

then

```
w=CenterDot[e,{f[x],g[x]}]
```

does not apply properly. It seems that Mathematica does not complete the process of applying the various operators to the functions f[x] and g[x].

You can try with the following operators to see the problem

```
I1:={{0 &, (x # + D[#,x] &)}, {0 &, - D[#,x] &}
I2:= {{0 &, x^2# &}, {0 &, D[#,x] &}
```

We see that with

```
u={f[x],g[x]}
```

the following are perfectly computed

```
CenterDot[I1,u]
CenterDot[I2,u]
CenterDot[CircleTimes[I1,I2],u]
```

but trying to evaluate thing like the anticommutator in the following way

```
I3:=Plus[CircleTimes[I1,I2], CircleTimes[I2,I1]]

CenterDot[I3,u]
```

one finds that Mathematica does not complete the evaluation and we are left with stuff.

My guess is that I should be telling Mathematica to apply the "Through" function as long as there are things to evaluate, but I am not sure how this can be done.

Hope this is clear :)

Many thanks !

I add the following for the sake of information; see the first answer for a better solution (I think).

As a way to have Mathematica evaluate everything correctly, I came up with the following modification of the CenterDot[a_,b_] function. It reads

```
CenterDot[a_,b_]:=FixedPoint[Through[#,Plus]&/@# &,#]&/@Inner[#1[#2]&,a,b]
```

This arranges for Mathematica to perform all evaluations, distributing over the sums. It is also suitable for combination with the CirclePlus[a_,b_] defined in the first answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a modification of your code that works. The problem was that you weren't combining the `Composition`s for each matrix entry correctly in `CircleTimes`: using `Plus` with `Composition` doesn't lead to a function which can be applied subsequently to another expression. You have to make each sum of compositions into a function itself.

First I'll copy the definitions that I didn't modify:

```
Clear[f, g, x];

I1 := {{0 &, (x # + D[#, x] &)}, {0 &, -D[#, x] &} }

I2 := {{0 &, x^2 # &}, {0 &, D[#, x] &}}

u = {f[x], g[x]};

CenterDot[a_, v_] := Inner[Through[#1[#2] &, Plus], a, v]
```

Now my modifications:

```
Clear[CircleTimes];
CircleTimes[a_, b_] := 
 Inner[Composition[#1, #2] &, a, b, 
  Function[f, Total@Through[{##}[f]]] &]


CirclePlus[a_, b_] := 
 MapThread[Function[f, Total@Through[{##}[f]]] &, {a, b}, 2]
```

The modification in `CircleTimes` is that I specified the replacement of the `Plus` operation in `Inner` as `Function[f, Total@Through[{##}[f]]] &` which is now itself a function that adds the individual operators *after* applying them to whatever argument `f` you provide.

Next, the same issue with `Plus` also arises in `I3`. So I defined an addition of operators `CirclePlus` in which the same trick is used as above, by combining the matrices of operators element-wise using `MapThread`.

Now the tests:

```
CenterDot[I1, u]

(* ==> {x g[x] + Derivative[1][g][x], -Derivative[1][g][x]} *)

CenterDot[I2, u]

(* ==> {x^2 g[x], Derivative[1][g][x]} *)

CenterDot[CircleTimes[I1, I2], u]

(*
==> {x Derivative[1][g][x] + (g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x], -(
   g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]}
*)

I3 := CirclePlus[CircleTimes[I1, I2], CircleTimes[I2, I1]]

CenterDot[I3, u]

(*
==> {x Derivative[1][g][x] - 
  x^2 Derivative[1][g][x] + (g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x], -2 (
   g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]}
*)

Id := {{1 &, 0 &}, {0 &, 1 &}}

CenterDot[CirclePlus[Id, Id], u]

(* ==> {2, 2} *)
```

As you can see, the tests produce outcomes that look correct. **Edit**: the last example is from the comment, and I changed the code to accommodate such constant operators. Note that this is not the same as the identity which *multiplies* the test function by `1`. My understanding of the comment was that the desired operator was meant to *replace* the test function by `1`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This explains a lot.

The only problem remaining is that something strange happens when the operators are ordinary matrices. For example if we want to add the Identity to the Identity with CirclePlus[a_,b_] as defined above, one gets thins like 2[f[x]] like "2" is an operator waiting to be evaluated. (Even though the identity was defined as a true operator)

Comment: Ah yes, that's because `Plus` inside `Thread` is not held unevaluated when its arguments have values that are known at the time of evaluation. To make it works for such cases it's probably best to avoid `Plus`  - I'll edit the answer to deal with the example you gave.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would define your functions, similar but I think simpler than @Jens answer:

```
ClearAll[CirclePlus, CircleTimes, CenterDot]

SetAttributes[CirclePlus, {Flat, Listable}]

CirclePlus[a__][x_] := Activate @* Through @* Inactive[Plus][a] @ x
CircleTimes[a_, b_] := Inner[Composition, a, b, CirclePlus]
CenterDot[a_, b_] := Inner[Compose, a, b]
```

For the OP example:

```
I1 := {{0&, (x # + D[#,x]&)}, {0&, -D[#,x]&}}
I2 := {{0&, x^2 #&}, {0&, D[#,x]&}}
u = {f[x], g[x]};
```

The same results as @Jens:

```
CenterDot[I1, u] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{g'(x)+x g(x),-g'(x)\right\}$

```
CenterDot[I2, u] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{x^2 g(x),g'(x)\right\}$

```
CenterDot[CircleTimes[I1, I2], u] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{g''(x)+x g'(x),-g''(x)\right\}$

```
I3 := CirclePlus[CircleTimes[I1, I2], CircleTimes[I2, I1]]
CenterDot[I3, u] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{g''(x)+x^2 \left(-g'(x)\right)+x g'(x),-2 g''(x)\right\}$

```
Id := {{1&, 0&}, {0&, 1&}}
CenterDot[CirclePlus[Id, Id], u] //TeXForm
```

> $\{2,2\}$

Comment: Very elegant (+1). It seems `Compose` was once a valid command...

Comment: It was deprecated in M2 (and replaced with `Composition`), but never removed. I wish it were still documented.

Comment: Interesting - there isn't really any consistency between use of nouns versus verbs for operations. E.g., `Add` doesn't exist, but `Subtract` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of my [`DifferentialOperator`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162590/45431) paclet to do this. Install with:

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/carlwoll/DifferentialOperator/releases/download/0.1/DifferentialOperator-0.0.3.paclet"]
```

and load with:

```
<<DifferentialOperator`
```

Here is an animation defining `I1` and `I2`

[image]

The other definition is:

```
u = {f[x], g[x]};
```

Now, let's check:

```
I1 . u //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{g'(x)+x g(x),-g'(x)\right\}$

```
I2 . u //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{x^2 g(x),g'(x)\right\}$

```
I1 . I2 . u //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{g''(x)+x g'(x),-g''(x)\right\}$

```
(I1 . I2 + I2 . I1) . u //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{g''(x)+x^2 \left(-g'(x)\right)+x g'(x),-2 g''(x)\right\}$