# Operator product

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, operators, products

I have this problem:

I define the gradient operator as:

```
gradiente = {D[#, x] &, D[#, y] &, D[#, z] &}
```

Now, if I want to apply the operator on a function i put:

```
Through[gradiente[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]
```

> `Out:  {2 x, 2 y, 2 z}`

How to define the laplcian??
I tried this but it doesn't work when I put it on a function:

```
laplaciano =Dot[gradiente, gradiente]
```

Comment: I found a solution:  laplaciano = `Tr[Through[gradiente[gradiente]]]`
but I think it doesn't work for polar coordinates...

Comment: Why do not you use built-in functions, or, otherwise,  `laplasiano=D[#, {x,2}]+D[#, {y,2}]+D[#, {z,2}] & `?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using some of the ideas from [an earlier answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5032/245), as follows (I'm reproducing some definitions from the link here, to be self-contained):

```
dx = Function[{f}, D[f, x]];
dy = Function[{f}, D[f, y]];
dz = Function[{f}, D[f, z]];

gradient = Function[ψ, Through[{dx, dy, dz}[ψ]]];

CenterDot[op1_List, op2_List] := Block[
  {ψ, x, y, z, functionBody},
  functionBody = Inner[Composition, op1, op2];
  (Function[ψ, Through[#1[ψ]]] &)[functionBody]
  ]

Clear[laplacian]

laplacian = {dx, dy, dz}·{dx, dy, dz};

laplacian[f[x, y, z]]
```

> $f^{(0,0,2)}[x,y,z]+f^{(0,2,0)}[x,y,z]+f^{(2,0,0)}[x,y,z] $

The first lines define the first derivatives with respect to the Cartesian variables, and then use those to construct the gradient. The `CenterDot` function is the new ingredient. It does the composition of gradients component-wise. I wrote it so that it can also be used to compose other vector operators. Since all my operators are `Function` objects, `CenterDot` also has to return such an object. But this has to be assembled from the operators given as arguments, which is done inside `Block`. The body of the resulting function is inserted into the `Function` only after the inner product of the two vector operators has been formed. This requires two steps because `Function` has `HoldAll` attribute so that the `Inner` wouldn't be evaluated at the proper time if I did it inside the `Function`.

Finally, I use that "operator operation" to construct the Laplacian.

The point of this is that you can now construct other scalar operators in the same way I did it for `laplacian`, by combining vector operators with a simple $\cdot$. This centered dot has the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>