# How to program Mathematica to do the differential operator calculation

Tags: vector-calculus, operators, differentials

I want to create a surface Laplacian under the spheroidal coordinates, 
Now, I already have the surface gradient defined, but I don't know how to find the Laplacian.

Since the surface gradient is too long, and it's a vector operator, I use this one as an example:

```
op[t_]:={Cos[t] D[#, t], Sin[t] D[#, t]}&;
```

Apply this on some u(t), I got:

```
In[540]:= op[t][u[t]]

Out[540]= {Cos[t] u'[t], Sin[t] u'[t]}
```

which is what I want.

However, I can't do divergence of this gradient. I've tried Composition, but it gives me a matrix instead of a scalar:

```
In[550]:= Composition[op[t], op[t]][u[t]]

Out[550]= {{Cos[t] (-Sin[t] u'[t] + Cos[t] u"[t]), Cos[t] (Cos[t] u'[t] + Sin[t] u"[t])}, 
           {Sin[t] (-Sin[t] u'[t] + Cos[t] u"[t]), Sin[t] (Cos[t] u'[t] + Sin[t] u"[t])}}
```

which is obviously wrong.

So, how can I get the Laplacian? Please help!

Comment: I use the double quote to make the codes look nice, the actual output has /[prime] within.

Comment: I think I just found a similar question with the dot product of operators: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75486/operator-product?rq=1

Comment: I guess I didn't state the problem clearly. My problem is to do the dot product of two vector operators. That's why I create this simple vector operator as a representation of my surface gradient operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not exactly get what you are doing there but the following should work in a general setting.

We start with a simple surface parameterization `f` (I simply use the sphere and compute the Riemannian metric `g` and the volume density `vol` induced on the parameterization domain by `f`. Then we apply a well known formula for the Laplace-Beltrami operator in terms of `g` and `vol`.

```
f = X \[Function] {Cos[X[[2]]] Cos[X[[1]]], Cos[X[[2]]] Sin[X[[1]]], Sin[X[[2]]]};

LaplaceBeltrami = u \[Function] 
   Quiet[Block[{X, XX = Table[X[[i]], {i, 1, 2}], Df, g, vol},
     Df = X \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[XX], {XX, 1}]];
     g = X \[Function] Evaluate[Df[XX]\[Transpose].Df[XX]];
     vol = X \[Function] Evaluate[Sqrt[Det[g[XX]]]];

     Evaluate[X] \[Function] Evaluate[
       Simplify[
        Tr[D[D[u[XX], {XX, 1}].Inverse[g[XX]] vol[XX], {XX, 1}]]/ vol[XX]
        ]
       ]
     ]
    ];

LaplaceBeltrami[u][{ϕ, θ}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I didn't state the problem clearly. My problem is to do the dot product of two vector operators. That's why I create this simple vector operator as a representation of my surface gradient operator. But it's also great to see your example! Thanks!