# Product derivative on derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

this is a silly question, probably. How to product derivative on derivative in Mathematica. I mean for example how to achieve this result:

[image]

Just more explanation. I need this for solving task with operators. I have two operators, for example:

[image]

I need to have the product of L1 on L2. When this is an operators of function y:

[image]

Comment: Nesting: `D[D[y[x, t], {x, 3}], {x, 1}, {t, 1}]`. Or just `D[y[x, t], {x, 4}, {t,1}]`.

Comment: general topic: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5030/5478

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    L1[u_] := D[u, x, \[Theta]];
L2[u_] := D[u, {x, 3}];
L3[u_] := L1[L2[u]];
L3[y[x, \[Theta]]]
```

yielding

[image]

Have fun!