# I want to be able to define (a(x) d/dx + b(x))^n

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, operators

I want to be able to define an operator

$(a(x) d/dx + b(x))^n$

where $d/dx$ is the derivative operator and $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are known functions and $n$ is a positive integer.

Related Query: How about defining

$ \prod_{i=1,...,n} (a_i(x) d/dx + b_i(x) )  $

where $a_i(x)$ and $b_i(x)$ are known functions and $n$ is a positive integer ?

Comment: I believe the result I was looking for was                                                                                                         abderiv[n_] =  Function[f, Nest[(a[x] D[#, x] + b[x] #) &, f, n]];

Comment: ...and the answer to the related query is most easily accomplished by a recursive procedure: abderg[0, x_] := f[x]  and                                abderg[n_, x_] := (a[x, n] D[abderg[n - 1, x], x] +  b[x, n] abderg[n - 1, x])

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done with [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html):

```
abderiv[n_] = 
  Function[f, Nest[(a[x] D[#, x] + b[x]) &, f, n]];

abderiv[0][f[x]]

(* ==> f[x] *)

abderiv[1][f[x]]

(* ==> b[x] + a[x] Derivative[1][f][x] *)

abderiv[2][f[x]]

(*
==> b[x] + 
 a[x] (Derivative[1][b][x] + Derivative[1][a][x] Derivative[1][f][x] +
     a[x] (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x])
*)
```

Here the order `n` is provided as the argument to a function that is itself a function acting on an arbitrary expression `f`. The assumption in the question seems to be that the differentiation variable is always `x`, so I don't specify this variable as an additional argument.

Comment: Thanks so much. I want to trouble you with a rejoinder.

Comment: More generally, If I define a function of three variables F(X,Y,Z) [which can be anything my whim decides]

 I want it to be meaningful when

 a) X,Y,Z are (complex) numbers

 b) X,Y are square matrices and Z is a complex number (say)

 c) X = d/dx, Y = \int dx, Z = x

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5030/245) and adapt it to your whims. To give more specific advice, it would be best if you show what code you've already written so that the parameters of the question are less hazy.

Comment: Sorry again. While the above question was just for kicks, I really need the answer to this now as I am working on something. It is a stupid question I admit but I am getting errors all over the place.

Comment: How does one define an operator such as                                     \prod_{i=1,...,n} (a_i(x) d/dx + b_i(x) ) with all the usual caveats.

Comment: @QuasarSupernova Could you formulate your followup question more carefully in a new post?  For example, it's not clear what this function `F` is supposed to do.

Comment: Sir/Maa'm, please answer my last question. I am stuck in my calculations because of that. The other one with F was just a very general question whose solution borders on AI perhaps.

Comment: @QuasarSupernova You really ought to mark this as accepted and post a followup question.  It's not good form to ask a question, get an answer, and then go "just kidding, that wasn't my question".