# How can I translate a MathWorld statement into Mathematica syntax?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, syntax

The Wolfram Mathworld has the following statement [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html):

> A derivative identity for expressing higher order modified Bessel functions in terms of $I_0(x)$ is $I_n(x)=T_n(d/(dx))I_0(x)$

However, I'm not sure how to translate that into Mathematica syntax.  My simple minded attempts have failed:

```
BesselI[l, x] /. {l -> 0.5, x -> 0.100}
D[ChebyshevT[l, x], x]*BesselI[0, x] /. {l-> 0.5, x -> 0.100}
ChebyshevT[l, D[BesselI[0, x], x]]*BesselI[0, x] /. {l -> 0.5, x -> 0.100}
ChebyshevT[l, D[BesselI[0, x], x]] /. {l -> 0.5, x -> 0.100}
```

Apologies for being obtuse if I've missed something obvious

Comment: Not sure how you wish to use the identity.  Related (defining differential operators): [(5030)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5030), [(15605)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15605), [(20519)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20519), [(71643)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71643), [(124370)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124370).  For fractional calculus: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=fractional+derivative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of my [`DifferentialOperator`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162590/45431) paclet to do this. Install with:

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/carlwoll/DifferentialOperator/releases/download/0.1/DifferentialOperator-0.0.1.paclet"]
```

and load with:

```
<<DifferentialOperator`
```

Then (I had to use an image since the partial derivative in the input doesn't translate well to MSE):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Waiting for a more elegant solution, you can try this:

Creates a differential operator from a polynomial in x:

```
DiffOp[poly_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] := Block[{Dop},
  Dop[c_, {ord_}] := c*(D[#, {x, ord - 1}] &);
  Return[Total[MapIndexed[Dop, CoefficientList[poly, x]]]];
  ];
```

For instance:

```
op = DiffOp[ChebyshevT[4, x]]

FullSimplify[op[BesselI[0, x]]]
```

> BesselI[4, x]

---

**Update:** maybe slightly better (and without Return[], see Carl Woll remark):

```
DiffOp[poly_, x_, f_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] := 
 CoefficientList[poly, x].Table[D[f, {x, i}], {i, 0, Exponent[poly, x] }]
```

For instance:

```
DiffOp[ChebyshevT[4, x], x, f[x]]
```

prints:
$$
8 f^{(4)}(x)-8 f''(x)+f(x)
$$

and

```
FullSimplify[DiffOp[ChebyshevT[4, x], x, BesselI[0,x]]]
```

returns

> Bessel[4,x]

Comment: It seems this is peculiar to the ChebyshevT or some such Std function.  If I try to use `(1/2*x^2*((Sqrt[1 - 1/x^2 + 1])^n + (Sqrt[1 - 1/x^2])^n))` inplace of ChebyshevT, the function is not evaluated.  I expect I've forgotten some other MMA fu?

Comment: @Hedgehog to define the differential operator the function expects a polynomial x^n -> d^n. In your example, you have a 1/x^2 term, thus not a polynomial. The function does not accept it due to the /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] test. If you want to manage negative x powers this is certainly possible, but you will get integro-differential operators

Comment: If you want to compute ChebT, the formula I have is: 1/2 ((x - I Sqrt[1 - x^2])^n + (x + I Sqrt[1 - x^2])^n) and there is no 1/x^2 term. Do not forget to FullSimplify the expression to let Mathematica recognize a polynomial before calling DiffOp[] (I will be back in one hour, sorry)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the idea is to translate the derivative operator (which must make this Q&A a duplicate, no?), this was what I came up with...

```
ClearAll[CircleDot];
(* assumes op is a polynomial with constant coefficients and the variable in f is x *)
CircleDot[op_, f_] /; PolynomialQ[op, Derivative[1]] && FreeQ[op, x] :=
   With[{c = CoefficientList[op, Derivative[1]]},
    c.NestList[D[#, x] &, f, Length@c - 1]
   ];

ChebyshevT[3, Derivative[1]] \[CircleDot] BesselI[0, x] // Expand
(*  BesselI[3, x]  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Interesting: Nested `D[#, x]` simplifies by `Expand`, but direct `D[#, {x, k}]` gives derivatives that do not simplify to the desired form.

Answer (score 2):

`Operate[]` combined with `Through[]` are suitable for this task:

```
k = 5; (* example *)
FullSimplify[Through[Operate[Composition[Through, ChebyshevT[k, δ]], BesselI[0, x]]] /.
             {(c_ /; FreeQ[c, δ])[BesselI][0, x] :> c BesselI[0, x],
              (c_. δ^j_.)[BesselI][0, x] :> c Derivative[0, j][BesselI][0, x]}]
   BesselI[5, x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Picaud Vincent, I create a differential operator to represent $T_n(d/(dx))$. Only I do it somewhat differently.

```
chebDOp[n_] :=
  Module[{rules, opExpr},
    rules = CoefficientRules[ChebyshevT[n, \[FormalU]]];
    opExpr = 
       Plus @@ 
         (#[[2]] D[BesselI[0, \[FormalU]], {\[FormalU], #[[1, 1]]}] & /@ rules);
    Function[\[FormalU], \[FormalV]] /. \[FormalV] -> opExpr]
```

Then

```
And @@ Table[FullSimplify[chebDOp[n][x] == BesselI[n, x]], {n, 4}]
```

gives

> `True`

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.  Your answer gives the same as Picaud, which, ironically is what I wanted.  But his seems simpler and possibly more general? in that I can pass in any polynomial and looks like it should work - I acknowledge this is not I requirement of the question.  Thanks again.