# Replacement of polynomial variable with differential operator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

I have a very simple question.

If I have a polynomial in x say, $f(x)$, how to construct the differential operator $f(\frac{d}{dx})$?

Failed Attempt:

```
In[739]:= f[x] = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3;

f[x] /. {x -> Function@D[#, x], x^n_ -> Function@D[#, {x, n}]}

Out[740]= a0 + a1 (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]#1\) &) + a2 (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x, 2}\)]#1\) &) + a3 (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x, 3}\)]#1\) &)
```

Comment: If $f(x)=2$, do you want $f(\frac{d}{dx})(x)$ to be $2x$ or $2$?

Comment: @Carl Woll I want it to be $2$

Comment: Ok, thanks, then my differential operator [paclet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162590/45431) would not be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x] = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3;
f1[x_] = (f[x] /. {x -> D[#, x], x^n_ -> D[#, {x, n}]}) &;
f1[x][Exp[m x]]
```

> a0 + a1 E^(m x) m + a2 E^(m x) m^2 + a3 E^(m x) m^3

Answer (score 2):

Rules can be shortened using the `_.` pattern. A function can be defined as

```
g[y_] := f[x] /. {x^n_. -> D[y, {x, n}]}
```

For example, `g[x^4]` gives

> a0 + 4*a1*x^3 + 12*a2*x^2 + 24*a3*x

Comment: ha ha, I am 10 seconds early :)