# Commutator of differential operators

Tags: differential-equations, algebraic-manipulation, pure-function, operators, differentials

Let $P_x = \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$, after specifying the commutator relation symbolically $[X, P_x] = i\hbar$, I can ask Mathematica to calculate commutator algebra. My question: is there a way for Mathematica to directly calculate this commutator without me specifying it? I've tried after searching and reading [pure functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html)

`x*(D[#, x] &) - (D[#, x] &)*x`

but it doesn't quite compute correctly.

Comment: Please make use of the search bar on top of this site; this question has been asked at least a dozen times before.

Comment: For computing it directly, maybe the following will help: `In[420]:= Together[
 Through[(Composition[x*# &, D[#, x] &] + 
      Composition[-D[#, x] &, x*# &])[f[x]]]/f[x]]

Out[420]= -1`

Comment: Thanks for the quick line Daniel! After more searching, I found a nice answer by Jens [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5030/having-the-derivative-be-an-operator/162590#162590)