# Performing operator expression on a function

Tags: operators, integral-transforms

What I want. I write an operator expression, and Mathematica performs it on a function.

Examples:

`E^(b D): f[x] -> f[x+b]`

`a^(x_ D): f[x] -> f[a x]`

`E^(Pi I /4 (D^2 - x_^2 +1)) :` Fourier transform (unitary, angular velocity)

`E^(D^2) :` Weierstrass transform

etc.
See here more: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1495596/2513

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162590/1871

Comment: What I want. I want to see what you have you tried. This is not a mechanical turk site.