# Partial derivatives as operators

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function which is a function of some scalar variables called :$x,y,t,\rho$ I want to calculate its derivative in the form of :
$(\partial_{t}-\partial_{z})^m (\partial_{x} -\partial_{y})^n$ where $m$ and $n$ could be 1,2,3,4 each time.How I can get this derivative correctly?To say the whole thing once:
$(\partial_{t}-\partial_{z})^m (\partial_{x} -\partial_{y})^n f(x,y,t,\rho)$,Could anybody help me?

Comment: I assume that the partial with respect to `z` is intended to be with respect to `ρ` then `der[m_, n_] = ((D[#, t] - D[#, ρ])^m*(D[#, x] - D[#, y])^n) &@f[x, y, t, ρ];`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5030/4999

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, It works. Thank you

Comment: @BobHanlon I think the OP wants the power of an operator, eg (d/dx)^n f(x)=f^{n} (x) giving the n-th derivative, but the code above just gives the power, eg (f'(x))^n. Maybe something with Fold would work.

Comment: @HansOlo - Thanks for explaining the notation used. I have posted an answer using a nested `Nest`

Comment: Great, thanks! It would also be nice if the OP clarified if this is what they wanted/meant (even though it seems the most likely to me).

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, Hans Olo stated that the powers used in the notation are intended to indicate the number of times the differential operators are applied.  I would then also assume that the product shown is intended to reflect concatenation of the operators. If that is the case, a nested [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) is needed

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dOp[func_, m_, n_] :=
 
 Nest[(D[#, x] - D[#, y]) &, Nest[(D[#, t] - D[#, ρ]) &, func, m], n]
```

For example,

```
dOp[f[x, y, t, ρ], 0, 0]

(* f[x, y, t, ρ] *)

dOp[f[x, y, t, ρ], 0, 1]
```

[image]

```
dOp[f[x, y, t, ρ], 1, 0]
```

[image]

```
dOp[f[x, y, t, ρ], 2, 2]
```

[image]