# Define a function whose variable is differential operator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I would like to act with a differential operator $D_x = x \partial_x^2+3\partial_x$ on a function $g(x)$ to compute something like
$$
((D_x)^2 +D_x) g(x)
$$
Clearly, in this simple example, this does the trick

```
dop[t_] := t  D[#, {t, 2}] + 3  D[#, t] &
dop[x][dop[x][g[x]]] + dop[x][g[x]]
```

However, in my case I have more derivatives and I would like to do things differently. I would like to more generally define a function $f(x) = x^2+x$ and then consider
$$
f(D_x)g(x) = ((D_x)^2 +D_x) g(x)
$$

How can I define this function $f(D_x)$ in Mathematica?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162590/1871

Answer (score 1):

We define an operator, that takes a polynomial in x and replaces every x by a derivative operator that acts on the variable x. To prevent that the operator is evaluated too early, we need "Hold":

```
op[der_] := 
 Evaluate[der /. x^(n_ : 1) :> Hold[D[#, {x, n}]]] & // ReleaseHold
```

Here is an example:

```
op[x + 2  x^2 + 3  x^3][x^3]

18 + 12 x + 3 x^2
```

Of course you may also define the operator that it take an arbitrary variable as argument to act on, but I want to keep it simple.

**Addendum**

If you want differential operators of the for of a polynomial like e.g. x ∂^2x, we may extend the above.

Define the operator as a function of d with coefficients  depending of x:

```
op[der_] :=  Evaluate[der /. d^(n_ : 1) :> Hold[D[#, {x, n}]]] & // ReleaseHold;
```

Now if we write e.g.:

```
op[x d^2][x^2]

2 x
```

Or

```
op[a  d^2 + b  x  d][x^2]

2 a + 2 b x^2
```

Or even:

```
op[Sin[x]  d][x^2]

2 x Sin[x]
```

Comment: The question needs an operator like $x ∂_x^2$; how would you enter that using your answer?

Comment: I'd be also curious to know

Comment: Look at the addendum.